# preg_replace and trim can't remove space character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string (in Russian):  `, Невский пр., д. 41` and I need to remove first space-comma-space sequence.

I've tried following: `$address = preg_replace('/^\s*,?\s*/i', '', $address);`

Doesn't match at all.

Then, for testing purposes: `$address = preg_replace('/ /', '', $address);`

Result: it matches all spaces except the first one.

Then: `$address = trim($address);`

Nothing happened with first space.

I checked if it's really space — [this service](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) told me `U+0020 : SPACE [SP]`

Have no idea what to check next.

Comment: Why not `preg_replace('~^\W+~u', '', $address)`? See https://3v4l.org/2iJF8. It will left-strip the string from all non-word chars. BTW, I can't repro your issue. Are you sure there is no BOM or some other non-visible char in front?

Comment: Good on you for actually testing the text. But that online service might not be too reliable (faux XHTML, lacking HTTP charset, missing enctype= on form). And copy&pasting on some platform/browser combinations can obfuscate Unicode into standard whitespace. Use and show a hexeditor or [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/bin2hex) sample of your original string.

Comment: sorry
1. stackoverflow successfully eat this apce before comma
2. I made an isolated test and both yours and mine regexp works, so apparently the problem isn't here

Comment: So what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If space and comma are to be removed at the beginning you can use [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) with a 2nd parameter.

```
$string = " , Невский пр., д. 41";
$string = ltrim($string," \r\n,");

echo "|".$string."|";
```

Output

```
|Невский пр., д. 41|
```